# Singly Linked Lists search

Tags: c++, nodes, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to make a search function that would look through my nodes for one with the same argument given but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this. My nodes(Element) consist of a pointer next_,T color_, and string name_. I need to return a pair with the node that I found and the previous node. If not found or no previous, then nullpointer.

```
template<typename T>
pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> PAL<T>::find(string name){
    pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> *result = nullptr;
    Element<T>* x = nullptr;
    Element<T>* y = nullptr;
    for (Element<T> *n = back_; n != nullptr; n = n -> next_){
        if (n -> name_ == name){
            Element<T>* x = Element<T>(n -> name_, n -> color_);
            result.first = x;
            result.second = y;
            break;
        }
        Element<T>* y = Element<T>(n -> name_, n -> color_);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is my first time doing these lists so I have no idea what I'm doing. I appreciate any kind of help and I can provide more info if needed! 
Thank you!

Comment: Do I make any sense? :/

Comment: Honestly I'd start by wrapping your head around a *much* more simplified linked list (without templates) of something trivial before trying this. There are signs something more fundamental (pointer management) is at play here, and you don't need template management adding to the malaise.

Comment: The fact that you are using `nullptr` suggests you are using C++11 or later, which has a single-linked [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) class in the STL. I suggest you consider using it instead of implementing this kind of stuff manually. But do you really need a **single** linked list? Because this would be so much easier with a **double** linked list (like [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing `std::pair`, and pointers in general.

Also, "*If not found **or no previous**, return null*", that second requirement doesn't really make sense for a general-purpose search function! Do you really want to ignore the first node in the list?

If so, try something more like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Element
{
    Element* next_;
    T color_;
    std::string name_;
};

template <typename T>
class PAL
{
public:
    //...
    std::pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> find(std::string name);

private:
    Element<T> *head_; // pointer to FIRST element
};

template <typename T>
std::pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> PAL<T>::find(std::string name)
{
    Element<T> *previous = nullptr;

    for (Element<T> *node = head_; node != nullptr; node = node->next_)
    {
        if (node->name_ == name)
        {
            if (previous != nullptr)
                return std::make_pair(node, previous);

            break;
        }

        previous = node;
    }

    return std::make_pair<Element<T>*>(nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> PAL<T>::find(std::string name)
{
    if (head_ != nullptr)
    {
        Element<T> *previous = head_;

        for (Element<T> *node = head_->next; node != nullptr; node = node->next_)
        {
            if (node->name_ == name)
                return std::make_pair(node, previous);

            previous = node;
        }
    }

    return std::make_pair<Element<T>*>(nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

But, if you really don't want to ignore the first node, then try this instead (and let the caller decide what to do if the previous node is null):

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> PAL<T>::find(std::string name)
{
    Element<T> *previous = nullptr;

    for (Element<T> *node = head_; node != nullptr; node = node->next_)
    {
        if (node->name_ == name)
            return std::make_pair(node, previous);

        previous = node;
    }

    return std::make_pair<Element<T>*>(nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I was just complicating my life! Thank you so much :D
Honestly, this is way easier to understand.